Absence of Excel number script coordinates
I have written the following script code and it has given me the monthly data of the annual growth of wheat from 2000 to 2023 in the form of graphs and Excel. Then I have added the slope of the corresponding file. But unfortunately, now I don't know which point this Excel output that he gave me as a monthly average is related to. Because my data does not have coordinates, how do I add the coordinates of the data output to my code?
Map.centerObject(AOI);
Map.addLayer(AOI)

//Time series 

var NDVI = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(AOI)
.filterDate('2022-09-01','2023-07-31')
.select('NDVI')
.map(function(image){
  var rescale = image.multiply(0.0001);
  
  var Range = rescale.gte(0.1).and(rescale.lt(0.3)).selfMask();
  var NDVI_range = rescale.multiply(Range)
  return NDVI_range.copyProperties(image,['system:time_start','system:time_end'])
});

print(ui.Chart.image.series(NDVI, AOI.geometry().bounds(), ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000, 'system:time_start')
.setOptions({
  title:"MDVI Range",
  vAxis:{title:'NDVI'},
  hAxis:{title:'Time'},
  
}));


